# How to load a image on image view from FTP URL in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ftp

I am trying to load image into a image view from FTP URL using the following code

```
    NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"ftp://50.63.12.12/bpthumb.jpg"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:imageURL];
    UIImage * image = [[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:request]autorelease];
    UIImageView *imgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 200)];
    [imgView setImage:image];
    [self.view addSubview:imgView];
```

But its not working.

I know I have to provide my `FTP` credentials to connect to `FTP` and get images in ma URL.

Please suggest me the way out.

Comment: the way out would be to tell us what exactly is not working so we can help you

Comment: NSData* imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: yourURLString]];

Comment: @ValentinShamardin:wat about the credentials.how it will connect to ftp?

Comment: @sujay, i am facing the same issue. So, Do you get any solution for this? If yes, can you share it? Thank you,

Answer (score 3):

Try this one :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"ftp://user:password@host:port/path"];
NSData *data = [NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

and here an [SimpleFTPSample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009243) from apple dev. try it .

Answer (score 1):

try somenthing like this in the connecion delegate didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge{

    NSLog(@"challenged %@",[challenge proposedCredential]);

    if([challenge previousFailureCount]==0){
        NSURLCredential *newCredential;
        newCredential=[NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"xxxxxx"
                                                 password:@"xxxx"
                                              persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential
               forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

    } else {

        [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        NSLog(@"Wrong username or password ");
    }


}
```

AXL

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use

`UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];`

But you shouldn't do that because that will use a synchronous data connection and will most likely freeze your app for the time being.
You should use a NSURLConnection with the appropriate delegates to download the image asynchronous.

For further tips on this topic take a look at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: i have tried using NSURLConnection . Its working for url with http but not for ftp url's.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with a path that starts with "ftp://" and it should just work. NSURLConnection supports http, https, ftp and file out of the box.

Comment: i have tried this . Its working for url with http but not for ftp url's.will this support for xcode 4.0.1